# JS Stop Propagation on the .on()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having issues where `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't seem to work on dynamic content.

```
  var blocks = '.embr-owner div, .embr-owner row, .embr-owner column, .embr-owner a, .embr-owner h1, .embr-owner h2, .embr-owner h3, .embr-owner h4, .embr-owner h5, .embr-owner h6, .embr-owner span, .embr-owner p'

  $(document).on("click", blocks, function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this))

    // Code
  })
```

I know the below works, however, I need to add more elements to the page which means I need to use the above event:

```
$(blocks).click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this))

    // Code
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue immediately after asking this question by just slapping a
`return false;` at the end, full code is as follows:

```
  var blocks = '.embr-owner div, .embr-owner row, .embr-owner column, .embr-owner a, .embr-owner h1, .embr-owner h2, .embr-owner h3, .embr-owner h4, .embr-owner h5, .embr-owner h6, .embr-owner span, .embr-owner p'

  $(document).on("click", blocks, function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this))

    // Code

    return false;
  })
```

Comment: `event` does not exist, so `event.stopPropagation()` does nothing. If you change `function()` to `function(event)` then `event.stopPropagation()` will work and then there is no need for `return false`.